# Using FFmpeg to join images with different timly distance

Tags: ffmpeg, slideshow

I have a set of images from which I try to create a slide show. On this [website](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images) I found the following command to do so:

`ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -start_number 126 -i img%03d.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4`

I got it working fine. But in my case I need to have each images to be displayed a different period of time. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try the concat demuxer and provide the duration for each frame.

1. Make text file containing the path to your inputs and the duration for each:

   ```
   file '/path/to/image0.png'
   duration 2
   file '/path/to/image1.png'
   duration 5
   file '/path/to/image2.png'
   duration 1.5
   file '/path/to/image3.png'
   duration 4
   ```
2. Then run `ffmpeg`:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart output.mp4
   ```

Notes:

- See the [concat demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1) for more info.
- The example won't work with an old `ffmpeg`, so make sure to [download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) a recent build first since FFmpeg development is so active.

Answer (score 0):

So it is some time ago I asked this question an there is no answer yet. I also did not find one by myself. I solved the task in my case by creating simbolic links for each frame pointing to the correct image. Then I set the framerate to 1. So for each second I want to display an image I have a symbolic link pointing to it.

One can of course also just copy the files accordingly. Depending on the total number of frames of the video this can result in a lot of disk space used. So I went with the links.